# How do I set a catchall email address with iCloud Mail+?

Tags: icloud, email, dns

I have added all the DNS records required for using the Apple's MX server but when I try to send an email to the address, it is rejected with the following message:

```
This is a system-generated message to inform you that your email could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. Details of the email and the error are as follows:
 
<email@domain.tld>: host mx01.mail.icloud.com[17.57.152.9] said: 550 5.1.1
<email@domain.tld>: user does not exists (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

Is there no way to add catchall email addresses (addresses that catch all emails sent to *@domain.tld) to [iCloud Mail+](https://beta.icloud.com/settings/)?

Presently, the settings page says the following:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It’s possible as of October 2022:

1. On iOS, open the **Settings** app.
2. Navigate to **Apple ID** > **iCloud** > **Custom Email Domain**.
3. Select your domain.
4. Turn on **Allow All Incoming Messages**.

*(Source: [support.apple.com](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/set-up-a-custom-email-domain-iph4de56a8a2/ios#iphb6adfee1e))*

Answer (score 2):

Currently no. The **Custom Email Domain** feature of `iCloud+` is currently a *beta service*. Since the service is still being tested, [it does not allow 2 letter email ids](https://appleinsider.com/articles/21/08/25/how-to-use-custom-email-domains-with-icloud). And, it currently [only allows 3 custom email ids](https://tidbits.com/2021/08/27/how-to-set-up-custom-email-domains-with-icloud-mail/) to be created per domain and per member (if you've enabled it for family too). So *catch all emails* to your domain on `iCloud+` will definitely not be possible right now, as otherwise, there wouldn't be a limit of 3 email ids per domain per member.